# Is there a name for sum of increases of f(x) on ranges where it's growing

Tags: terminology

It would be useful for "how hard a biking road is" or "how much could you earn on a particular stock without shorting it".

Comment: I would suggest a name like "positive part of the total variation."

Comment: *On ranges where it's growing* the "sum" (really, integral) of increases would just be the total change.

Comment: Function sin(x) has total change between 0 and 10PI equal to 0, but it has positive part of total variation equal to 10.

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I know, but one can write down a formula (supposing that $f$ is differentiable, with $f'$ Riemann-integrable):
$$
\int_a^b f'(x) H(f'(x)) dx 
$$
where $H$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).